# How can i handle multiple combinations of query parameters in a resource class efficiently?

Tags: java, java-stream, jax-rs, resteasy, querydsl

I have the case where i need to write resource classes for our API that take more than four query parameters, and the number of `if else` statements i need to write is equivalent to the cardinality of the power set of all those query parameters, so in case of 4 query parameters, i need to write 16 if else statements, 5 -> 36 etc.

Is there a better was to do what i am trying to do?
**Stream API** is not a good option since this is an enterprise application and the number of entities is 30000 and more and there are a lot of users using the API and we had `OutOfMemoryError` in the past.

I am using **Querydsl**, and i can't pass **null** values to the `eq()` method.

Comment: Will having default values help you out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed the parameters from the controller to the facade and did the following using **Querydsl**

```
public List<Entity> findAll(Optional<Integer> opId, Optional<String> opName) {
    final QEntity q = QEntity.entity;

    final BooleanBuilder where = new BooleanBuilder();

    opId.ifPresent(id -> where.and(q.id.eq(id)));
    opName.ifPresent(name -> where.and(q.name.eq(name)));
        
    return new JPAQuery.where(where).list(q);
}
```